# How do I reference the current row in a vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table of names, levels, and comments that need to use the name in each line. The names are in the first table, and the comments based on level are in a separate table. So if I add Kirk and select level 1, it would insert 'Kirk is great.' into the Comment field.

| Name | Level | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spock | 2 | Spock is pretty good. |
| McCoy | 1 | McCoy is great. |

| Level | Comment Bank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME is great. |
| 2 | NAME is pretty good. |

How do I reference NAME as the actual field in another table, purely based on the level?

I have tried using vlookup which means I can match the level to the comment in the bank, but obviously that just copies the information and doesn't change NAME in the comment itself to Spock or McCoy.

I tried using INDIRECT() in the comment bank but it just pulls whatever the field is from the row that it's in. EX: if the second table's data is in I25:J26, INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE) will just reference I1 as the first column in that particular row. This does not translate over to the first table, so it would just put:

| Name | Level | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spock | 2 | NAME is pretty good. |

I'm not sure what else to try or if I'm barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the first table in A1:C and the second table in E1:F, you can use the following formula in C2 and drag down.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B2,E$2:F,2,0),"NAME",A2)
```

Or use a single formula in C2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,E2:F,2,0)),"NAME",A2:A))
```

Comment: This was absolutely FANTASTIC and worked perfectly, and so simple! I was definitely making it more complicated than it should have been, lol. And even better, I was able to extend it on my own and apply it to learn even more, i.e. chaining substitutions so I could add a 'Hobby' column and change the comment bank to be 'NAME is pretty good at HOBBY'. Thank you so much!